# AS3 mp4 save file

Tags: actionscript-3, ffmpeg, stream

I would like to save an mp4 file using AS3 to a user selected directory.
mp4 is a big file and I would like to download a part of the file (for instance 10 sec) and save to local directory.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

I found a solution that uses ffmpeg that may be compiled as swf and then used from AS3, but not sure how to send the stream from Flash to ffmpeg.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please clarify do you need just to save downloaded mp4 file (it's easy), or to encode raw video or something else?

Comment: Just need to download a part of mp4 (not full file, but let's say 10 seconds from 1 hour) and save to a local file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a trivial task as far as I can see there is 2 ways to do it. 
1. Use ffmpeg from command line (it works only with Adobe AIR) and convert stream from internet to file locally. You can use library (proxy exe) giving you full access to cmd like this https://code.google.com/p/periscopic/source/browse/
You should read ffmpeg docs about this way.
2. Read specification of mp4 file format and try to slice stream and save it locally.
I have no idea which way easier.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about both solutions, but the app needs to be executed in the browser. Also if ffmpeg will be used, it needs to download full file before processing, so if file has 1 hour in length, but I need only 10 sec, it may be very slow.
For the second solution, I was thinking about this, but maybe there is an easy solution?

Comment: I never looked into mp4 format, but it may be not as hard as you think. and if you're working in browser this is the only way

Comment: OK, thanks, the problem is that input file can be mp4, mov or m4v.
So, I was thinking if there is a solution that will work for all formats.
Otherwise I will need to parse each file separately and save to an output file.
Thanks anyway.